# ASP.NET GridView Header Column right-justified - asp:LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

Researchers,

I have an issue in with ASP.NET GridView Header not setting alignment - LinkButton value set to right-aligned. I tried HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" on asp:TemplateField and also tried separately with , both did not work. Any thhing I can try? ItemTemplate edit box is correct by setting : text-align:right;  (values appearing right justified with asp:TextBox. Please provide ideas, thank you.

```
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Price" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="true"  OnCommand="Sort_Click" CommandArgument="Price" align="right" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            $<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>' style="width: 50px; text-align:right;"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            $<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' style="width: 50px; text-align:right;"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="120px" />    
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. The below works on asp:LinkButton

`style="display:block; width: 60px; text-align:right"`

Comment: Hi, can you please review the below link and provide any advise? Thanks,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960295/add-extention-pdf-or-doc-to-the-no-extention-source-file-in-root-attachments-fol